# Is there any way to get around incompatibilities for Microsoft Lync without uninstalling other Microsoft software?

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, compatibility, lync, lync-2013

I need to install Microsoft Lync.  I am using a 64-bit Windows 8.1 system, and I have tried installing both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Microsoft Lync Basic 2013.

When I try to install the 32-bit version, I get this message:

> We can't install the 32-bit version of Office because we found the following 64-bit programs on your PC:
>
> Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013
>   Microsoft Office 32-bit Components 2013
>
> Please uninstall all 64-bit Office programs, then retry installing 32-bit Office.  If you want to install 64-bit Office instead, please run the 64-bit setup.

When I try to install the 64-bit version, I get this message:

> We can't install the 64-bit version of Office because we found the following 32-bit programs on your PC:
>
> Microsoft Access database engine 2010 (English)
>
> Please uninstall all 32-bit Office programs, then retry installing 64-bit Office.  If you want to install 32-bit Office instead, please run the 32-bit setup.

I no longer have the installers for the Microsoft Access/Microsoft Office software, as I don't have access to the webstore I purchased them from.  I do not want to uninstall any of my software, but Lync won't install without me doing so.  Is there a way to get around this (e.g., editing registry keys), or am I at an impasse here?

Comment: What exactly is the question those error messages are pretty clear.

Comment: My question is "How do I bypass these errors without uninstalling any software?"

I don't see why having software on the computer should necessarily conflict.  It's not as if I need the "correct" version of the software to run.  It just says that I can't have the "incorrect" version.  

Uninstalling the software I have is an undesired result, as is not being able to install Lync.  I could try doing a system backup/rollover, but that would take up too much time.  I was hoping that there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: 32-bit and 64-bit Office software cannot co-exist on the same machine.  Your question doesn't have an answer except to uninstall software.  The most elegant solution you have is to uninstall 32-bit software or the 64-bit software then reinstall the same bitness